# How to get data of particular position in recyclerview using volley

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

well i'm trying to get data of particular position in Recyclerview using volley 
but don't know how to do it

let me explain it

i have two layout in a row (i'm using gridlayoutmanager) so i want to make every layout clickable and after clicking the layout i wanna show a fragment which will contain all the data of that particular position like any other shopping app do.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onClickListener on the inner layout that you want to make clickable. After that, open your activity / fragment and there make the calls you want to the back end using Volley.

Comment: json will come as the response of your volley call. Layout positions doesn't have json by itself, the server you send you a json back. Read a bit of webservices (REST) and client server architecture